# Does adb backup include contacts?

Tags: adb, contacts, backup

Does the command:

```
adb backup -all -f backup.ab
```

include contacts in the backup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it would not backup Contacts. Yes, it would backup Contacts.

*Confused*, eh!

> Yes, it would backup Contacts.

See this question: [Backup/Restore SMS/MMS via ADB on a non-rooted device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/114437/96277) The author of it was able to backup contacts. It was later revealed that the device on which the backup was performed ran Android 4.1.2. It was a bizarre revelation for me that the backup succeeded.

> No, it would not backup Contacts.

As per the Manifest mentioned [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/+refs) for default Contacts Provider app in Android versions (in series), for Jelly Bean and above Android versions the ADB backup for Contacts Provider/Storage would be denied by system, and hence your contacts wouldn't be backed up.

It's a mere flag `android:allowBackup="false"` that's the cause of backup denial. See my answers [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/115021/96277) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/115519/96277) to know more about that flag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. You can get it via:

```
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db
```

Comment: But `adb pull` is not `adb backup`! Also, your command would not work  for a device running  the kernel  in secure mode.

Comment: It is most useful knowing exactly where to fetch the contacts from in their raw format. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should include the contacts. Your syntax appears incorrect though. It should be
`adb backup -all -f backup.ab` rather than `adb backup .all -f backup.ab` Also the `-f backup.ab` is optional as that is the default.

Comment: No, it [wouldn't include the contacts](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/118778/96277), though your syntax part is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be the case. I tried with both the following commands

```
adb backup -all -apk -shared -nosystem -f adb_backup.ab
adb backup -all -apk -shared -system -f adb_backup.ab
```

and neither my photos, SMS nor contacts were backed-up.

Comment: I don't know about photos but you're right about SMS and Contacts not getting backed up. See my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/118778/96277) to know the reason. Also, on which Android version did you test these commands?