# Extract Contacts from ADB backup?

Tags: adb, contacts, backup

I have a full backup from Cyanogenmod 12. I need to extract the Contacts and add them to Cyanogenmod 13. I found attempting a restore just breaks things because it restores dalvik data and system caches, which are simply wrong between these versions.

How do I either (1) restore only the contacts; or (2) extract the Contacts from the ADB backup for manual restoration?

Comment: ADB backed up Contacts? since when? Related: [Does adb backup include contacts?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/118778)

Comment: Use titanium backup

Comment: @Firelord - Oh my; that would be surprising. I have to ask (in jest): what's the purpose of an `adb backup --all` if it does not backup all the data?

Comment: @jww Probably security/privacy considerations.  This way if the backup file falls into the wrong hands, most of your critical data (contacts, 2-factor authentication accounts, most banking apps) is not exposed.