# how to take complete backup of my android device using adb

Tags: adb, shell, backup-manager

I'm trying to take full backup using `adb backup -all -f <path>` and it took backup and stored in my PC.

When I try to restore it using `adb restore <path>` then it restores onto the target device.

ADB backup command is not taking backup of messages, contacts and pictures. Kindly guide me if I'm missing something.

I could see that I have to use `adb root` to take backup using `pull` command. Will the device warranty be there if I use `adb root` command?

Comment: If you have not rooted your device, 'adb root' will not work at all.

Comment: @Dan B, still the posting doesnt have solution or guidance for getting backup of contact and messages

Comment: Well, lets be realistic here. Contacts can either be saved to the SIM card, or be exported onto storage and moved onto a computer as a file. Backing up SMS can only really be done to the SIM card, unless apps are used. Pictures can be saved to google photos, or synced/moved to the Backup holder.

Comment: See conveniently named "SMS Backup & Restore£ in the play store. It backs them up as .xml files, so those can be moved like normal files in the backup procedures.

Comment: Oh, and you can use the -shared and -system arguments in the link above to help this process along.

Comment: you mean that  -shared and -system parameters will get backup of contacts and messages

Comment: they have done in personal experience. Ryan's answer was a very good one, and even if parts don't work, exporting contacts and messages to .xml files get them backed up anyways. Google has been backing up our images since the introduction of google photos for free, remember, so no worries there.                                        (PS: The pound sign in a different comment is meant to be a " whoops)

Comment: @SeekeR you seem to want a complete device back up with all apps and data on the phone, You should use a recovery Backup instead of ADB backup

Comment: @RahulParashar , i did try to reboot the device with "adb reboot recovery" it reboots he device in recovery but it shows No Commands in the center and i could not see anhy menu. MotoG first generation with OS 5.1 version.

Is there any other way to get complete backup from command line like how backup & restore, super backup apps do.

Comment: You can add the menu to recovery by flash another recovery to the device.
CWM recovery has all Backup options.
I recommend flashing CWM Recovery. You would have to root your device to use this.

Answer (score 0):

For photos you can either copy them to the pc or use a third party app that will backup them,  like Google photos.

For contacts and sms there are plenty of third party apps.  You can alao backup the contacts to google server using the contacts app itself

Comment: I'm developing a application to take a backup from the mobile to PC. I have tested some of the tools which takes full backup. But i wanted to know how did they achieved it and what was the commands used behind the GUI.

Comment: well I don't think they used any official API, but instead they just copied files from each app's folders. The thing that they miss is permissions. For this, I think you need to look at : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27866435/878126 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/32798532/878126 .

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. it seems the command list the permission granted for th apk and not to set permission to allow some operation.

is there any other command other than adb to take backup of contacts from device ?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible so easily as backup of apps, but some people say it is: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85269/does-adb-backup-include-contacts